# Change js confirmation to nice confirmation of jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using js confirmation. I want to make it more [beautiful with jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Using js confirmation:

```
$("a.delete").click(function() {
    el = $(this);
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want delete the data?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr("href"),
            type : "GET",
            dataType : 'json', //The requested response in JSON format
            success : function(response) {
                if (response.status == 1) {
                    loadData();
                    $("#divFormContent").load("ajax.php?module=test&action=form_test");
                    $("#divFormContent").hide();
                    $("#btn_hide").hide();
                    // alert("The data successfully deleted!");
                } else {
                    alert("Data failed in the clearing!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Can anybody tell me how can I change it using jquery UI confirmation?

Comment: you should check, http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/"  jQuery Alert Dialogs (Alert, Confirm, & Prompt Replacements)

Comment: A DEMO for jAlert on http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create the element which will be displayed. Sample html:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:5px 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

The element will be automatically hidden when you call `.dialog()` on it passing the `autoOpen: false` parameter. Do it inside the DOM ready handler preferably.

jQuery UI's dialog boxes are **asynchronous**, they won't freeze the function and wait for a response as the `confirm` prompt does. Instead, you have to wrap your function inside the "Yes" confirmation button's callback.

When you need the dialog then, just call `$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");`.

And to finish, `this` will no longer reference the clicked element when you move your function from the click handler to the dialog's callback handler. I used [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the clicked `$(this).attr('href')` in the `#dialog-confirm`'s data and retrieve it for the Ajax call.

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.delete").click(function() {
        $('#dialog-confirm').data('clickedHref', $(this).attr('href'));
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : $('#dialog-confirm').data('clickedHref'),
                    //rest of your function here
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/KvXdv/)

Comment: Thank you so much Fabrício Matté.